# Facebook's avatar page unavailable

Tags: facebook

I recently encountered an issue while trying to create an avatar on Facebook. When I attempt to access the Facebook Avatar page, I receive a message, "This Page Isn't Available Right Now."

This error suggests a technical issue on Facebook's end. Reloading the page makes no difference.

If anyone knows why I am experiencing this error, or how to resolve it, please let me know.

Comment: @BlindSpots The issue is still ongoing.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the URL of the page you are trying to access as well as the browser you are using.  Also include the results of trying to access the same page in your browser's incognito/private mode.

Comment: "*I attempt to access the Facebook Avatar page*" — How does one do this?